# what happens and what should happen when an asker accepts a wrong answer?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

In [this question (about how to check version number for numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520234/how-do-i-check-which-version-of-numpy-im-using), they answer accepted by the asker, as been commented by multiple people, as not being neither standard, nor the recommended method.

What should be done in order to correct that ? (The asker seem to have been inactive for nearly the last 10 years)

Obviously, this is not a duplicate of «[Why do incorrect answers keep getting “accepted”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7572/why-do-incorrect-answers-keep-getting-accepted)». I don't care about the why. What I'm looking for is a way to solve the problem.

Here we have a situation where  :
1/ It has been documented by multiple users, why the answer should not be the accepted one. It works, but the standards do not accept it as the recommended way of doing. And
2/ Since it is tagged as being the accepted answer, it receives supplementary likes from people which are glad with the first solution they find and won't even check comments or other answers

It is quite obvious than normal users won't be able to do it and that it requires help from someone with administrative rights. My question is about how we do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do incorrect answers keep getting "accepted"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7572/why-do-incorrect-answers-keep-getting-accepted) ***or*** https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169891/282094

Comment: You could vote for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/keeping-special-status-for-accepted-answers-without-sticking-them-to-top-forever - if implemented, the answer you are referring to would have lost its top spot many years ago.

Comment: @PolyGeo : I don't think it will work because the solution works. It's just not the documented right way to do it, but since it's first (and works), it keeps getting likes.

Answer (score 6):

If it's wrong, downvote it. As someone other than the OP, that's all you can do. Future users will see the downvotes and can weigh that against the acceptance themselves. If there aren't any such comments already, you can also leave a comment noting what's wrong with the answer (although that answer already has comments).

People are free to accept answers as they see fit. Acceptance means that it helped them, not that the answer was the most correct. As a question asker, they likely aren't in a place to judge what answer is the most correct anyways.

Comment: There already are multiple comments explaining why it should not be the accepted answer and since it is first, it keeps getting likes. So disliking won't help, and we probably need an OP intervention.

Comment: @Camion You have to trust new visitors to look over the different solutions for themselves. I'm not sure what you're referring to by "OP intervention" though.

Comment: in the example I mentioned, it obviously didn't work for 10 years, So this trust you recommend, looks more like faith, to me. About the OP, I was refering to the same OP you mentioned in your answer.